# Postgres dump inserts in order

Tags: postgresql, bash

I'm trying to write a bash script that dumps data from remote db and restores it inside a local docker container.
The problem is there are like 90 tables with a lot of foreign keys but the data dump does not seem to care about the ordering of inserts. What can I do about this so it would actually insert all rows?

This is how I'm dumping things currently

```bash
#Dumps roles
pg_dumpall --roles-only -U $user -h $db_url -p $port --clean --file=roles.dump
#Dumps schema
pg_dump --clean -s --host $db_url --port $port --user $user $db_to_dump > backup-schema.dump
#Dumps data
pg_dump --column-inserts --host $db_url --port $port --user $user $db_to_dump -n $schema_to_dump > data.dump
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's not how you do it. If you insist in splitting data and object definitions, do it like this:

```bash
pg_dump --section=pre-data --clean -f pre.sql mydb
pg_dump --section=data --clean -f data.sql mydb
pg_dump --section=post-data --clean -f post.sql mydb
```

Then you restore them in that order. `pre.sql` will contain the object definitions, `data.sql` the data and `post.sql` all the index and constraint definitions. That way, you restore the data before restoring the constraints, and there is no problem with the order of the tables. Besides, restoring the data is much faster if the indexes and constraints are not yet defined.

Comment: This works, thank you. However, the size of the remote database is 2.9 GBs, when I dumped it the size of the file was 2.6 GBs and when I imported the size of the local database was 2.2 GBs. Any idea what's happening here?

Comment: That's normal. The difference between the old and the new database are bloat, and an index does not take up any space in a `pg_dump`.

Comment: That's an unrelated question...